# why does look up HTTPS Publication Destination via webdav url has extra "/"?

Tags: core-service

I am using the PowerShell Core-Service module (https://code.google.com/p/tridion-powershell-modules/) and I can easily obtain the schema Publication Target Destination by tcm id:

```
$schema1 = Get-TridionItem -id "tcm:0-3-8"
```

However, I can not look up the HTTPS schema for Publication Target Destination by webdav url unless I put in a double //. When I open the HTTPS schema in the CME, I see it's webdav url (or location) is simply "\" so, I would expect this should work:

```
$schema2 = Get-TridionItem -id "/webdav/HTTPS.xsd"
```

but it tells me there is no item with that ID. however, if I when I looked it up by tcm id, it told me that the webdav location is actually /webdav//HTTPS.xsd and indeed this works:

```
$schema2 = Get-TridionItem -id "/webdav//HTTPS.xsd"
```

Can anyone explain why this is the case? I can look up our schemas without this double // (e.g. "/webdav/C020%20Shared%20Global%20Content%20US%20English/Building%20Blocks/System/Content/Administration/Administrative%20Alerts/Dashboard%20News%20and%20Notifications.xml")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not 100% sure why you need to know that :)

The reason is that a webdav URL structure is made up of /`WEBDAV PREFIX`/`REPOSITORY`/`Path`/`to`/`item`.

Protocol schemas are system-wide objects, and therefore do not have a `REPOSITORY`. If you use a URL like /`WEBDAV_PREFIX`/HTTPS.xsd, then Tridion will search for a publication named `HTTPS.xsd`. By omitting the repository you're basically telling Tridion "look in System Wide objects". I agree Tridion could have used a keyword there, like "SYSTEM", but then you wouldn't be able to use that keyword as a publication name.

Comment: Thanks Nuno. I am building a tool to read an excel file of publish target urls and set them. this is for after doing db refresh from production. i have to reset the publication targets for the environment back to its original setting. in order to do that, I have to create new Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.LinkToSchemaData object and set its IdRef. I thought it best to look up the HTTPS schema by webdav url instead of assuming its id doesn't change.

Comment: Makes perfect sense to use WebDAV urls, and I agree. The 'why' was related to the double slash, not the use case.